# What is the best approach for defining Lambda function for API CRUD?

Tags: aws-lambda

Can anyone let me know what is the best approach in defining a lambda function for API CRUD? I have these two options. Let me know which one is better. You can assist me even much better approach if any.

1. Create individual lambda function for each Http Method?
2. Create one lambda function and in the body, separate each request by using httpMethod? Here is the sample code for both approaches:

1st approach:
In the first approach, I have separate lambda functions for each request.

```
exports.get = async event =>
{                                 
 //TODO: code here
}

exports.post= async event =>
{                                 
 //TODO: code here
}
```

2nd approach: 
In the second approach, I have one lambda function and in the body, the APIs are separated.

```
exports.handler = async event => 
{
   if(event.httpMethod ==='GET')
   {
     //TODO: code here
   }
   if(event.httpMethod ==='POST')
   {
     //TODO: code here
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if this is the best solution, but I would suggest for you to take a look at [Serverless Express](https://github.com/awslabs/aws-serverless-express) . It maps the request that comes trough API Gateway so that you can use it with Express. You can then use API Gateway's [greedy proxy](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/api-gateway-set-up-simple-proxy.html) resource to route all resources to the same lambda.